# The definition of the limit adopted from multivariable calculus

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

We consider two definitions of the limit of a real function of one real variable.

I. The limit is a real number $L$ so that, given an arbitrary real number $\epsilon > 0$,
there is a $\delta > 0$ such that, for any $x$
satisfying $0 < |x - c| < \delta$, it holds that $| f(x) - L | < \epsilon$.

II. The limit is a real number $L$ so that, given an arbitrary real number $\epsilon > 0$,
there is a $\delta > 0$ such that, for any $x$
belonging to the domain of $f$ and
satisfying $0 < |x - c| < \delta$, it holds that $| f(x) - L | < \epsilon$.

The first one is classical, and the second one is adopted from the multivariable calculus. In other words, does calculus of $n$ variables also work for $n=1$? Would the second definition cause any problems?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If something holds for $n \in \mathbb N$ then it should hold for $n=1$. Also what is $|\cdot|$ in your question for the multivariable case?

Comment: But that is my question, whether we can take the definition II from the multivariate calculus also for $n=1$. You can see that it is different from I, the classical one. And of course, $|\cdot|$ is nothing but the absolute value in II

Comment: You don't tell us what you think "a real function of one real variable means". I think that it means we are talking about a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ in which case I and II are identical. If you don't mean that, then you've got to say what you do mean, and make sure that I applies in the restricted situation.

Comment: Of course I mean such functions. And then see my comment below.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference I see between the two definitions is that in the second one you add “$x$ belonging to the domain of $f$”, so I deduce that this is causing you some confusion.
Clearly this condition is implicitly assumed also in the first definition, otherwise when you write $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$, what would $f(x)$ even mean?

Comment: But this difference has consequences. For example $\lim_{x\to 1} \arcsin(x)$ does not exist according to I, but it is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ according to II.

Comment: The two definitions are only phrased differently, but they coincide. As I wrote, the first definition already assumes $x$ to be in the domain of $f$. I can imagine that with the first definition you would wonder about how to evaluate the limit for $x \rightarrow 1^+$, but the thing is that you simply don't, since $x$ would not belong to the domain of $f$, hence $f(x)$ has no meaning.

Comment: So how to comment the well known theorem "limit exists if and only if left and right limits exist and are equal" from this point of view?

Comment: You always have to consider relative (to the domain of your function) neighborhoods of the accumulation points. In your example, we are talking about sets like $(1-\epsilon,1]$ i.e. open neighborhoods of 1 in the domain of the function. In the limit notation, this translates to considering only $\lim_{x\to1^-}arcsin(x)$. When computing a limit of a function you are evaluating how the function behaves when taking values arbitrarily close to the accumulation point, hence it does not make sense to consider values outside the domain of the function, even if they are close to the accumulation point